# How to change the background of a GridSplitter when focused/dragged in XAML (with a border)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridsplitter

I found it weird that there's no GridSplitter property like "DragBackground" or something alike.

This seems to work though:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomGridSplitterStyle" TargetType="GridSplitter">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridSplitter">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" >
                        <!-- Background -->
                        <Rectangle Fill="White" StrokeThickness="0" />
                        <!-- Focus Visual -->
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

```
  GridSplitter Style="{StaticResource CustomGridSplitterStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Width="6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  BorderThickness="2,0,0,0" BorderBrush="Blue" />
```

My problem with this solution however is that I'd like to set a border on the left side of the GridSplitter (see above), which doesn't work when using the custom GridSplitter style.
Does anybody know how to get this working ?

Comment: So what do you want to do? Set `FocusVisual.Opacity` to 1 when dragging?

Comment: @dkozl I'd like to have a GridSplitter that **a)** has a specified color when I'm dragging or focusing it (white in my case) [already solved this part] **b)** has a border on the left side [this doesn't work with my solution and neither when I set Opacity to 1]

Comment: I see nothing that would do something on dragging or focusing. So you just want to bring `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush` into your `Template`?

Comment: @dkozl Oh, that's true. I cut the style (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278070(v=vs.95).aspx) a bit as I only needed the same color as the background when dragging/focusing. _So you just want to bring BorderThickness and BorderBrush into your Template?_ Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` in your `Template` you can use `TemplateBinding` on some `Border`. You can also use `Setter` in your `Style` to define some default value.

```
<Style x:Key="CustomGridSplitterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridSplitter">
                <Border 
                    x:Name="FocusVisual" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="FocusVisual" Property="..." Value="..." />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Also since `GridSplitter` is a `Thumb` and as such has [`IsDragging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb.isdragging(v=vs.110).aspx) property so you can create `Trigger` to do something when it is true as in the example above